# Setting TH min and max width extremely slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

Given a fixed-header HTML table, I'm trying to line up the header columns with the body row columns.  I'm doing this because the CSS I'm using to make the headers fixed results in the headers being out of alignment with the rest of the body.

The javascript I'm using works, but is extremely slow.  Any ideas on how I can speed this up?

Here's the fiddle showing the problem.  Right now it's taking about 5+ seconds for a relatively small table.
http://jsfiddle.net/w93NU/

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function fixedHeader($table) {
    //This function compares the header row with the first body row and lines up all of the widths
    var firstRowTds = $table.children("tbody:first").children("tr:first").children("td");
    var headerRowThs = $table.find("th");

    for (var i = 0; i < firstRowTds.length; i++) {
        var head = headerRowThs[i];
        var cell = firstRowTds[i];
        var width = (Math.max($(cell).outerWidth(), $(head).outerWidth())) + "px";
        //Here are my problem pieces.  Setting these values are what kills the perfomanrce
        $(cell).css({
            "min-width": width,
            "max-width": width
        });
        $(head).css({
            "min-width": width,
            "max-width": width
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: See my new answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after much trial and error, if you comment out the last item in the style sheet, then it is fast.  I don't know why.

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w93NU/4/)

```
/* fixed width for THs */
/* the tbody needs to be 16px less than the thead, for the scrollbar */
/*#readiness-grid tbody td {
    width: 242px;
}*/
```

Comment: That cut the time down to about 1.5 seconds.  Worthy of being marked as answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
// changing:
var firstRowTds = $table.children("tbody:first").children("tr:first").children("td");
var headerRowThs = $table.find("th");
// to:
var firstRowTds = $table.children("tbody:first > tr:first > td");
var headerRowThs = $table.find("thead > th");
```

scopes the node lookup and cuts the time from ~800ms to ~2ms between the start/end times on your sample table.

Comment: Just changing those two lines doesn't work.  The columns don't size properly.

Comment: My apologies - in the fiddle it showed a speed increase in the js, I didn't consider the column widths themselves.